# How can I run Linux in a VM on a Retina MacBook Pro in Hi-DPI mode?

Tags: linux, osx, virtualbox, vmware, resolution

I use a Retina MacBook Pro. I run Linux in virtual machines for development work.

I occasionally use the Linux GUI directly in the virtual machine, but most of the time I ssh (with the -Y parameter) from the Mac terminal to the box and run Eclipse and Firefox, for example, form there. This launches the Mac X-Windows server - used to be X11.app and now XQuartz.

My Linux GUI is always in normal resolution - whether in the VM or in the Mac X-Windows app.

What can I do to make it work in Hi-DPI mode?

Depending on the project, I can use Oracle Linux, CentOS, or Ubuntu (using the default/most popular desktop).

Similarly, depending on the project, I can use VirtualBox or VMware Fusion.

Answer (score 3):

If you have VMware Fusion installed on your Mac one solution could be going to the selected Virtual Machine Settings and check both **Accelerate 3D Graphics** (Which requires VMware Tools installed on that virtual machine) and **Use full resolution for Retina display** (To enable *Retina display support* in selected virtual machine) in **Display** Setting.

[image]

BTW, Here's a useful [link](https://www.tekrevue.com/tip/hidpi-mode-os-x/) about HiDPI Mode in Mac OS X to get more information on it.

Comment: This [article](https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2034670) can also help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use Parallels for Mac, it seems that they support High-DPI resolution. In this article of their KB, they talk about the windows support but I think it should work also for Linux:
http://kb.parallels.com/114700

Comment: Aah. The third option. :( I take it this is to do with the kind of 'hardware' the virtual machine presents to the guest OS?

Answer (score 0):

If the following advice isn't working, you may need to increase the resolution from within the virtual machine. Go to Settings - Displays (which may not be visible, in which case search for "displays" in the application search bar) then increase the resolution that ubuntu operates under to a larger and larger size until you're comfortable with it. If the text is too small, increase the zoom factor on that as well.